# How do I make a bootstrap row the length of my viewport?

Tags: html, css, razor, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a row that needs to be the length of the viewport, rather than ending where the text ends.

```
    <div class="col-sm-2 bg-color-bold">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="major-header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="general-text">
            Lorem ipsum oluptua no diam consetetur dolore erat dolor nibh no sea lorem et dolores rebum sanctus amet accusam invidunt est nostrud praesent soluta justo consetetur ea sanctus takimata eirmod ut dolores kasd takimata justo illum clita at sea nam amet feugiat
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The row by nature is only the height of my text, and stops when the text ends, but I need the row to be the length of the page.

Comment: make row `height=100vh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `height: 100vh;` in the row?

Comment: Like inline styling? or somewhere else?

Comment: Can be in a style="height: 100vh" inside the html tag or with a custom css class.